# How to eagerly load nested association with count

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have 4 models, in a chained set of has_many relationships:

```
Account
  has_many :source_configs
  has_many :fetches, :through => :source_configs

SourceConfig
  has_many :fetches

Fetch
  has_many :social_contents

SocialContent
  # end of the line
```

From **Account**, I want to get all associated **SourceConfigs**, all **Fetches** associated with each SourceConfig, and a *count* of the **SocialContent**'s associated with that Fetch.

And I'd like to use as few queries as possible. Currently, accessing the counts results in a "SELECT COUNT(*) ..." for each **Fetch** - which is taking a while.

Currently, my controller **#show** method looks like

```
@account = Account.includes(:source_config => :fetches).find(params[:id])
```

and in the view, I reference:

```
@account.fetches.each do |fetch|
  fetch.count
end
```

which results in multiple SELECT COUNT() calls.

I know how to write the SQL to include the counts with the selection of Fetch objects:

```
%{
  left outer join (
    select sc.fetch_id as fetch_id, count(*) as social_contents_count
    from social_contents sc
    group by sc.fetch_id
  ) sc_count on (sc_count.fetch_id = fetches.id)
}
```

That might not be totally right, but good enough - I can tweak it and that's not the real problem.

The real problem is I can't figure out how to package up that statement into the **includes** call to make it work.

Creating a named scope did not work for me (although I probably did it wrong).

```
# in source_config - doesn't work
scope :fetches_with_social_content_count, :class_name => "Fetch" do |foo|
  fetches_with_social_content_count
  joins( %{ left outer join (
              select sc.fetch_id as fetch_id, count(*) as social_contents_count
              from social_contents sc
              group by sc.fetch_id
            ) sc_count on (sc_count.fetch_id = fetches.id)})
end

# try to use it: no worky
@account = Account.includes(:source_configs => :fetches_with_social_content_count).find(params.require(account_param))
```

Any ideas?